# how to solve this error: Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : invalid multibyte string 68

Tags: file-upload, txt

I need to load a txt file to do a PCA analisis and it used to work but started telling me that error after I actualice R and Rstudio. How can i solved it?
i tried to load the file as csv and xlxs and it didn´t work.
i need row.names=1 and header = true but doesn´t let me

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem after updating RStudio to a recent version.
I solved this problem by adding code that specifies the encoding format, such as `csvfile <- read.csv("yourfilename.csv", header = T, fileEncoding="utf-8")`. You may have to change the file encoding format if you used an encoding other than utf-8.

I hope it's not too late for you.